# Is there a way to use variables in Cucumber Examples data table?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Basically, I was looking for a way to use some kind of Java variable in Cucumber Examples data table. So that post-execution, when a report is generated, I should be able to view the current value of variable used as part of a particular Step in place of the referenced data table cell.
Consider today's date or timestamp, for example, Since I do not want to hard code these variables. Without the use of variables, all scenarios looks the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for isn't a good practice, just the opposite.

When the code depends on current datetime, it is a good practice to mock the current datetime for testing purpose.

You can either pass the current datetime as an argument, or to inject it.

When testing, you pass a hardcoded datetime, which would be a precondition of the test case.

When running the app in production, you pass the real current datetime.

Java has an useful type for mocking current datetime called Clock.

**UPDATE:**

Regardless to mock datetime or not, you cannot use variables in Cucumber scenarios because it has no sense. BDD is about providing concrete examples with concrete data. Variables used in scenario outline are just a way to put together multiple scenarios (one for each combination of values we give to variables in a datatable).

Comment: Thank you for the reply @choquero70. Probably, the date/timestamp example I gave, wasn't the most appropriate one I could think of. Originally, I was thinking of storing Base URI for my Web services in some kind of configuration and then use this variable in Cucumber Example. This is going to help me in getting rid of the need for replacing BaseURI values in every feature file (Cucumber Example), whenever there's a change in execution environment (QA or Dev). Please note that, I'm using these features for running automated tests.

Comment: For such situations there exists the concept "scenario background" , where you place preconditions (given parts) that you are going to use in multiple scenarios. Setting up the base uri value is such a precondition

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

Bumped on this while looking for a way to print resolved variables to the cucumber report. I support the below comments on explicitly writing test data, but I had the same kind of issue.

I'm using cucumber for integration tests where we do not have control on the underlying systems and I like to have acceptance-style tests in my set to verify things end to end. One of the items depends on date intervals.

I introduced variable notation in `${varhere}` style. Then I went a step further and added a 'variable type' sort to speak. After tinkering around with GroovyShell a bit I can now write `${#Groovy#LocalDate.minusYears(18).minusDays(1).toString()}` and it gets evaluated. Hacky, and you need to centralize it in the framework to not triple over it every time you create something new. And also you need to have a way for the evaluated values to find its way to the reports.

Fun as an exercise. Might be useful in some environments to have some light scripting in some scenario's. Discuss all you want about the intended use of cucumber - it's used as a test execution engine with a DSL sometimes.

If you depend on those kinds of things you might want to think about maybe getting those tests out of cucumber and running them as purely code in addition to the set of cucumber tests.

Second way of doing it: have a step with a variable and evaluate that.

`^When I create a user that has age (\d+) years$`

Now you can take the integer as an argument and set the date that way. That's more cucumber-ish than the first part of the message in this exposé. I should have led with this. :)